# Store an Android library file in bintray

Tags: android, gradle, bintray, jcenter

I am new in android app development. I have to store a android library in bintray but I am not getting file upload option. What should I do so that I can get file upload option? my android library's build.gradle file is below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

apply plugin: 'realm-android'

ext {
    PUBLISH_GROUP_ID = 'cyd.awesome.android'

    PUBLISH_ARTIFACT_ID = 'awesome-material'
    PUBLISH_VERSION = '1.0'
}

android {

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true  // shrink
            useProguard true   // don't obfuscate

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro' http://stackoverflow.com/      }
    } }

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {

        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test:runner:0.3') {

        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support annotations'
    }

    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test:rules:0.3') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'

    //network
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'

    //beacon
    compile 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.+'

    //geofence
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'

    //firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:10.0.1'

    //parsing json
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    //compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.3'

    //testing
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
    //testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0"

    //reactive
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'

    //beacon Monitoring
    //compile 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2+'

    //disk storage
    //compile 'com.squareup.sqlbrite:sqlbrite:1.1.1'
    //compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.4'

    //geofire
    //compile 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.1'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/blundell/release-android-library/master/android-release-aar.gradle'
```

Comment: Please look at https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin

Comment: This article discusses all the steps involved in making a bintray account and publishing using the `gradle-bintray-plugin`: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Building-your-own-Android-library

Comment: Read the following article for details, it states everything in details.It states everything to upload a library to bintray and hence to Jcenter in so much detailed fashion. 

https://medium.com/@abhishekint16/upload-your-first-android-library-1892c23aea0f